# In math, how to express the tangent contact with the function

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

In math, I want to say that there is no possibility that an asymptote will be a tangent to the function.

How should I write it?

Comment: Could you please give us an example sentence with a series of blanks? Because, you see, when you say "asymptote", it already means that a given function will never touch it (horizontal asymptotes can be crossed though). That information is already contained in the word "asymptote". However, you could say something like this: **a function gets asymptotically close to a given vertical/horizontal line.**

Comment: my study is about horizontal asymptote, the students' error is that they think that vertical and horizontal are equal - can't touch the function. one of their mistakes is that they think the asymptote can intersect the function but can't be a  tangent to the function

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying. An asymptote just can't be tangent to a function at a point because it never touches the graph of the function. The concept of tangency states that the graph of a function and a line to tangent to the function at a particular point only touch each other at that particular point called the point of tangency. Asymptotes and tangent lines are completely different animals. I think you've got everything backwards.

Comment: `y=(x^2)/(1+x^4)` is tangent to `y=0` at `(0,0)`.  As x goes to positive or negative infinity, `y=0` is an asymptote of `y=(x^2)/(1+x^4)`  I would tell your students that in a range where one function is asymptotically approaching another, the two functions can touch or be parallel, but cannot be tangent to one another.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

> The asymptote cannot be a tangent to the function.

Comment: I would not recommend reposting - you shouldn't post the same question on multiple SE sites. We can migrate the question if it doesn't get a good answer here.

Answer (score -1):

My sentence would be:

> The tangential asymptote could not hold on the function.